# PyQt Save Image from QTableView to SQLite DB using Delegate

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, store

I am able to select the image from the directory and store in the specified cell, but I can't work out how to get it to save to the Database. I hit enter or tab and the image just goes away.

Here is the delegate I am currently using

```
class ImageDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate): 

    # def createEditor(self, parent, option, proxyModelIndex):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):

        self.lbText = qtw.QLabel(parent)
        self.lbText.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.printFileLoc = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent,  caption = 'Open Print', filter = '*.jpg')
        self.lbPixmap = qtg.QPixmap(self.printFileLoc[0]) #[0] brings back path to image
        self.lbText.setPixmap(self.lbPixmap.scaled(70,100, qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        return self.lbText


    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):

        self.plants_model = qts.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.plants_model.setTable('plant_list')
        self.plants_model.setData(index, self.lbText, qtc.Qt.EditRole)
```

And here is where I am using an instance of the delegate class

```
    self.imageDelegate = ImageDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('photo'),
            self.imageDelegate)
```

Any ideas?

****Minimal Reproducible code as requested:

```
import sys, csv
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtSql as qts
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5.Qt import QFileInfo
import sqlite3
from datetime import date
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class DateDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, proxyModelIndex):
        date_inp = qtw.QDateEdit(parent, calendarPopup=True)
        return date_inp


class ImageDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate): 

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, proxyModelIndex):

        self.lbText = qtw.QLabel(parent)
        self.lbText.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.printFileLoc = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent,  caption = 'Open Print', filter = '*.jpg')
        self.lbPixmap = qtg.QPixmap(self.printFileLoc[0]) #[0] brings back path to image
        self.lbText.setPixmap(self.lbPixmap.scaled(70,100, qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        return self.lbText


    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):

        self.plants_model = qts.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.plants_model.setTable('plant_list')
        self.plants_model.setData(index, self.lbText, qtc.Qt.EditRole)


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.gridLayout = qtw.QGridLayout()
        self.mainW = qtw.QWidget()
        self.mainW.setLayout(self.gridLayout) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainW)

        # Connect to the database
        db = qts.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('plants.db')
        if not db.open():
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
                None, 'DB Connection Error',
                'Could not open database file: '
                f'{db.lastError().text()}')
            sys.exit(1)


        #CREATE MODELS FOR EACH SQL TABLE
        self.zone_model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.zone_model.setTable('zones') 

        self.loc_model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.loc_model.setTable('loc_rec') 

        self.indoor_seed_model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.indoor_seed_model.setTable('indoor_seed')

        self.soil_rec_model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.soil_rec_model.setTable('soil_rec') 

        self.plant_type_model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.plant_type_model.setTable('plant_type')

        self.nick_name_model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.plant_type_model.setTable('nick_name')    

        self.plants_model = qts.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.plants_model.setTable('plant_list')

        self.plants_model.setRelation(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('nickname_id'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('nick_name', 'id', 'veggies')
        )

        self.plants_model.setRelation(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('ans_id'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('indoor_seed', 'id', 'ans')
        )
        self.plants_model.setRelation(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('zone_id'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('zones', 'id', 'code')
        )
        self.plants_model.setRelation(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('soil_id'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('soil_rec', 'id', 'soil_type')
        )
        self.plants_model.setRelation(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('p_type_id'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('plant_type', 'id', 'p_type')
        )
        self.plants_model.setRelation(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('location_id'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('loc_rec', 'id', 'loc')
        )

        self.UIComps() # call the UI components method

    def UIComps(self):
        # set headers for main table
        fieldnames = ['ID', "Year Planted", "Real Name", "Nick Name", "Description",
        "Seed Plant Rec","Garden Plant Rec", "Plant Notes", "Comments",
        "Days to Germ", "Days to Harv","Reco Spring Frost","Actual Spring Frost",  "Seed Plant Rec", "Garden Plant Rec",
        "Actual Seed Plant", "Actual Garden Plant", "Harvest Date Plan", "Actual Harvest Date",
        "Photo", "Location", "Zone", "Seed Indoor?", "Soil Type", "Plant Type" ]

        c = 0
        for f in fieldnames:
            self.plants_model.setHeaderData(c, qtc.Qt.Horizontal, (fieldnames[c]))
            c += 1

        self.plants_model.setEditStrategy(qts.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.plants_model.dataChanged.connect(print)

        lbl2 = qtw.QLabel("View/Edit Plants", self)   
        lbl2.setFont(qtg.QFont("Helvetica", 25, 12)) 
        self.gridLayout.layout().addWidget(lbl2, 6, 0,1,3, alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)

        #PLANT LIST TABLE
        self.plant_list = qtw.QTableView()

        self.plant_list.setModel(self.plants_model)
        self.gridLayout.layout().addWidget(self.plant_list, 7, 0, 2, 3)
        self.plant_list.horizontalHeader().setSectionsClickable(True)
        self.plant_list.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.plant_list.setSortingEnabled(True) # this makes table sortable

        self.dateDelegate = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('seed_plant_date_reco'),
            self.dateDelegate)

        self.dateDelegate2 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('garden_plant_date_reco'),
            self.dateDelegate2) 

        self.dateDelegate3 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('seed_plant_date_ac'),
            self.dateDelegate3) 

        self.dateDelegate4 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('garden_plant_date_ac'),
            self.dateDelegate4) 

        self.dateDelegate5 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('harvest_date_plan'),
            self.dateDelegate5) 

        self.dateDelegate6 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('harvest_date_ac'),
            self.dateDelegate6) 

        self.dateDelegate7 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('spring_frost_reco'),
            self.dateDelegate7) 

        self.dateDelegate8 = DateDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('spring_frost_ac'),
            self.dateDelegate8)  

        #IMAGE INPUT
        self.imageDelegate = ImageDelegate()
        self.plant_list.setItemDelegateForColumn(
            self.plants_model.fieldIndex('photo'),
            self.imageDelegate) 

        self.plants_model.setEditStrategy(qts.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.plants_model.dataChanged.connect(print)                                  

        self.plants_model.select() 

        self.plant_list.setItemDelegate(qts.QSqlRelationalDelegate())

        #adding toolbars
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Controls')
        deleteCoffee = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon("close.png"), "Delete Record", self)
        deleteCoffee.triggered.connect(self.delete_plant) #removes from table
        self.toolbar.addAction(deleteCoffee )

        addPlant = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon("add.png"), "Add A Plant", self)
        addPlant.triggered.connect(self.add_plant)
        self.toolbar.addAction(addPlant)


    # SLOTS for Toolbar buttons
    def delete_plant(self):
        selected = self.plant_list.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected or []:
            self.plants_model.removeRow(index.row())  
        self.plants_model.select()
        self.countRecords()

    def add_plant(self):
        self.gridLayout.layout().addWidget(self.plant_list, 7, 0, 2, 3)
        self.plants_model.insertRows(0, 1) 
        self.countRecords()#calls the countRecords() function


app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("fusion")
mw = MainWindow()
mw.setGeometry(10, 10, 1000, 750)
mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

AND THE DB

```
CREATE TABLE zones (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    code TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
    ;

CREATE TABLE loc_rec (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    loc TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
    ;   

CREATE TABLE indoor_seed (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ans TEXT 
    )
    ;

CREATE TABLE soil_rec (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    soil_type TEXT  
    )
    ;  

CREATE TABLE plant_type (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    p_type TEXT  
    )
    ;  

CREATE TABLE nick_name (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    veggies TEXT NOT NULL 
    )
    ;  

INSERT INTO nick_name(veggies) VALUES
    ('Artichoke'),
    ('Asparagus'),
    ('Bean Sprouts'),
    ('Brocoli'),
    ('Brussels sprouts'),
    ('Cabbage'),
    ('Cauliflower'),
    ('Celery'),
    ('Greens-Bok Choy'),
    ('Greens-Chard'),
    ('Greens-Dandelion'),
    ('Greens-Kale'),
    ('Greens-Spinach'),
    ('Herbs-Basil'),
    ('Herbs-Chamomile'),
    ('Herbs-Lavender'),
    ('Herbs-Oregano'),
    ('Herbs-Parsley'),
    ('Herbs-Rosemary'),
    ('Herbs-Sage'),
    ('Herbs-Thyme'),
    ('Lettuce-Iceberg'),
    ('Lettuce-Romaine'),
    ('Mushrooms'),
    ('Onions-Chives'),
    ('Onions-Leeks'),
    ('Onions-Onion'),
    ('Onions-Shallots'),
    ('Onions-Scallions'),
    ('Peas'),
    ('Peppers-Bell'),
    ('Peppers-Chili'),
    ('Peppers-Jalapeno'),
    ('Peppers-Habanero'),
    ('Peppers-Paprika'),
    ('Peppers-Tabasco'),
    ('Peppers-Cayenne'),
    ('Radicchio'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Beets'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Beetroot'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Carrot'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Ginger'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Parsnip'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Potato'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Rutabaga'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Radish'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Sweet Potato'),
    ('Root Vegatables-Turnip'),
    ('Sweetcorn'),
    ('Squashes-Acorn'),
    ('Squashes-Butternut'),
    ('Squashes-Banana'),
    ('Squashes-Cucumber'),
    ('Squashes-Pumpkin'),
    ('Squashes-Spaghetti'),
    ('Squashes-Zucchini'),
    ('Stevia'),
    ('Tomato'),
    ('Watercress'),
    ('Waxed Beans')
    ;      

INSERT INTO zones(code) VALUES
    ('1a'), ('1b'),
    ('2a'), ('2b'),
    ('3a'), ('3b'),
    ('4a'), ('4b'),
    ('5a'), ('5b'),
    ('6a'), ('6b'),
    ('7a'), ('7b'),
    ('8a'), ('8b'),
    ('9a'), ('9b'),
    ('10a'), ('10b'),
    ('11a'), ('11b'),
    ('12a'), ('12b'),
    ('13a'), ('13b') 
;                   

INSERT INTO loc_rec(loc) VALUES
    ('Walipini'),
    ('Garden'),
    ('Barrel'),
    ('Deck'),
    ('Office'),
    ('Kitchen')   
    ;

INSERT INTO indoor_seed(ans) VALUES
    ('Yes'),
    ('No') 
    ;

INSERT INTO soil_rec(soil_type ) VALUES
    ('Very Wet'),
    ('Wet'),
    ('Dry'),
    ('Very Dry')
    ;

INSERT INTO plant_type(p_type ) VALUES
    ('Indetermined'),
    ('Semi-Determined'),
    ('Determined')
    ;    


CREATE TABLE plant_list(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    plant_year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    real_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    nickname_id INTEGER REFERENCES nick_name(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    fruit_desc TEXT ,
    seed_plant_rec TEXT,
    gard_plant_rec TEXT,
    plant_notes TEXT,
    comments TEXT,
    germ_days INTEGER,
    harv_days INTEGER,
    spring_frost_reco DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    spring_frost_ac DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    seed_plant_date_reco DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    garden_plant_date_reco DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    seed_plant_date_ac DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    garden_plant_date_ac DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    harvest_date_plan DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    harvest_date_ac DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    photo BLOB,
    location_id INTEGER REFERENCES location_rec(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    zone_id INTEGER REFERENCES zones(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ans_id INTEGER REFERENCES indoor_seed (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    soil_id INTEGER REFERENCES soil_rec (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    p_type_id INTEGER REFERENCES plant_type (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
    ;
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Here is the full code for the app as requested

Comment: share the .db ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is that the delegate shows what is stored in the roles so in this case you must save the information of the file(image) in the role, and then use that information to show it as a centered icon:

```py
class ImageDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            parent, caption="Open Print", filter="Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"
        )
        if filename:
            model = index.model()
            file = qtc.QFile(filename)
            if file.open(qtc.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
                model.setData(index, file.readAll(), qtc.Qt.EditRole)

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        pixmap = qtg.QPixmap()
        if pixmap.loadFromData(index.data(qtc.Qt.EditRole)):
            option.features &= ~qtw.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDisplay
            option.text = ""
            option.features |= qtw.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDecoration
            option.icon = qtg.QIcon(pixmap)
            option.decorationSize = pixmap.size() / pixmap.devicePixelRatio()
            option.decorationAlignment = qtc.Qt.AlignCenter
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. However, when I try to implement this as I get to the cell where the image belongs.... I am getting the following error:  ....

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 34, in initStyleOption
    if pixmap.loadFromData(index.data(qtc.Qt.EditRole)):
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  loadFromData(self, bytes, format: str = None, flags: Union[Qt.ImageConversionFlags, Qt.ImageConversionFlag] = Qt.AutoColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  loadFromData(self, Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray], format: str = None, flags:

Comment: Union[Qt.ImageConversionFlags, Qt.ImageConversionFlag] = Qt.AutoColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: @ctacta1 what are python and pyqt5 version?

Comment: Python 3.7.2 &  PyQt5 5.14.1

Comment: @ctacta1 Try deleting and creating the table, I think the error is caused by some previous data from your attempts